# How to add an hour to Twitter time (date (ISO 8601))?

Tags: python, datetime, twitter, timedelta, iso8601

I just want to add an hour to the Twitter time format. The one I got is:

```
start_time = '2021-03-11T00:00:00.000Z'
```

I googled for several hours now, but nothing works. I always get errors such as the time date does not match the format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one...

Install *python-dateutil* then:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import timedelta

start_time = '2021-03-11T00:00:00.000Z'
d = parser.isoparse(start_time)
d += timedelta(hours=1)
print(f"{d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]}Z")
```

The strftime function produces 6 decimal places. So, to keep your original format you'll need to strip off the last 3 digits then add the Z